# Beautiful Soup filter function fails to find all rows of a table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a large html document using the Python Beautiful Soup 4 library.

The page contains a very large table, structured like so:

```
<table summary='foo'>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            A bunch of data 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            More data 
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        100s of <tr> tags later
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a function that evaluates whether a given tag in `soup.descendants` is of the kind I am looking for. This is necessary because the page is  large (BeautifulSoup tells me the document contains around 4000 tags).
It is like so:

```
def isrow(tag):
    if tag.name == u'tr':
        if tag.parent.parent.name == u'table' and \
                tag.parent.parent.has_attr('summary'): 
            return True
```

My problem is that when I iterate through `soup.descendants`, the function only returns `True` for the first 77 rows in the table, when I know that the `<tr>` tags continue on for hundreds of rows.

Is this a problem with my function or is there something I don't understand about how BeautifulSoup generates its collection of descendants? I suspect it might be a Python or a bs4 memory issue but I don't know how to go about troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still more like an educated guess, but I'll give it a try.

The way `BeautifulSoup` parses HTML heavily depends on the [underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). If you don't [specify it explicitly](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), `BeautifulSoup` will choose the one automatically based on an internal ranking:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

In your case, I'd try to switch the parsers and see what results you would get:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")  # needs lxml to be installed
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")  # needs html5lib to be installed
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")  # uses built-in html.parser
```

Comment: Thanks, yours was a well educated guess. After switching to python's built in parser `html.parser` I was able to return all 304 lines of the table, as opposed to the 77 I got when it was parsed with lxml.